# Finite index non-normal subgroups of free groups.

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Consider a free group on some variable set $A=\{a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n\}$

$n$ is dependent on us, we can choose it.

I want to find some finite indexed non-normal subgroup of this free group on $A$.

For example how can we construct a subgroup $H$ of Free group on $\{a,b\}$ which is non-normal and index of $H$ is $3$? I know some methods to find normal subgroups but for non-normal subgroups I can't construct.

For normal subgroups

Consider a map $$\phi:F_2\to \mathbb Z_n\\a_1\to \bar 0\\ a_2\to \bar 1\\ F_2/_{<ker\phi>}\simeq \mathbb Z_n$$

And yes we know $\{(1),(1,2)\}\subset S_3$ is non normal subgroup but how to relate this fact to free groups? How can I find index 3 non normal subgroup?

Comment: What have you tried? For example, have you thought about the $n=2$ case? And can you give us examples of index $2$ subgroups, just do we know what you know and what form you expect the solution to take?

Comment: For example for normal subgroups I can send $a_1\to \bar 0, a_2\to \bar 2$ via $\phi:F_2\to \mathbb Z_n$, so $a_2^n=Id$

by isomorphism theorem $F_2/<ker\phi>\simeq \mathbb Z_n$ I guess I can find all normal finite index subgroups but I cannot reach for non normal ones

Comment: Ok great, although I guess that $\overline{2}$ should be $\overline{1}$? You should add this to your question. Then you should think: Do you know any finite groups with non-normal subgroups of index $3$?

Comment: @Jale'de jaled, you probably know group $S_3$.

Comment: yes for example $\{(1),(1,2)\}$ is non normal subgroup of $S_3$ but how can I relate to this free group?

Comment: You can define a homomorphism $f:F_2 \to S_3$ with $f(a) = (1,2,3)$, $f(b) = (1,2)$.

Comment: Yes I also think that after writing my last comment that 2 and 3 cycles generate $S_3$ But after that How can I guarantee index 3 non normal subgroup? I cannot divide it by kernel since kernel would imply normal subgroup but I guess I can say $f/<ker f>$ has non normal subgroup part in $F_2$ in some sense but I cannot connect the ideas, Can you give me a bit hint

Comment: You should know the correspondence theorem for subgroups of quotient groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For normal subgroups we can use homomorphisms, and the kernels themselves will be our normal subgroups as suggested in the OP. For non-normal subgroups we can still use homomorphisms, but finding the subgroups requires an extra observation:

> Let $\phi:G\twoheadrightarrow H$ be a surjective group homomorphism. If $K$ is a non-normal subgroup of $H$ then $\phi^{-1}(K)$ is a non-normal subgroup of $G$. Moreover, $|H:K|=|G:\phi^{-1}(K)|$.

This result is pretty standard and not too hard to prove. For example, it follows from the [Correspondence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem_(group_theory)).

So, writing $F_n$ for the free group of rank $n$, to find a non-normal subgroup $L$ of $F_n$ with index $i=|F_n:L|$ we simply have to find a finite group $H$ which can be generated by $n$ elements and which contains a non-normal subgroup $K$ of index $i$; as $H$ can be generated by $n$ elements there exists a map $\phi:F_n\twoheadrightarrow H$, and then $L:=\phi^{-1}(K)$ has the required properties by the above observation.

For $i=3$, take $H$ to be the symmetric group $S_3$ (this can be generated by $2$ elements, and hence by $n$ elements for all $n\geq 2$ as we don't really care about repetition), while it contains a non-normal subgroup of index $3$, say $K=\{id, (12)\}$.

For general index $i$, take $H$ to be the symmetric group $S_i$ and take $K$ to be canonical image of $S_{i-1}$ in $S_i$ (all permutations of $\{1, \ldots, i\}$ which fix $i$), so here $|S_i:K|=i$. Moreover, $K$ is not normal in $S_i$ because for example $(12\cdots i-1)$ and $(23\cdots i)$ are conjugate in $S_i$, but $(12\cdots i-1)\in K$ as it fixes $i$ while $(23\cdots i)\not\in K$ because it does not fix $i$.